# Calculate the time taken until a submit button is clicked

Tags: jquery, jsp, date, jquery-plugins, jstl

I have a form fields in a web page to be filled out.i need to calculate the time difference from when the page is opened until the submit button is clicked
the time difference calculated will be stored in the same bean as for fields

I knew on how to get the time in JSP using

```
<jsp:useBean id="today" class="java.util.Date" />
<p>Time: <strong><fmt:formatDate type="time" value="${today}" /></strong></p>
```

But how to find the submit button on click event is triggered and to find the time difference ?

Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks for your time ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by creating a new `Date()` object on `$(window).load` and comparing it with another `Date()` object that's created on clicking the button.

**Here's the Code:**

```js
// Run when the page is fully loaded including graphics. 
$( window ).load(function() {
 var timeStart = new Date();

  $("#submit").on('click', function() {
    var timeEnd = new Date();
    var timeDiff = timeEnd - timeStart;
    console.log(timeDiff);

    $("#time").html('Time Difference: ' + timeDiff + ' ms');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <button id="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<h1 id="time"></h1>
```

Here's the [codepen link](http://codepen.io/arslanhawn/pen/ByvROG)

Hope this answers your question.